# How full of people does our solar system have to become, to cause massive destruction to it?

Tags: hard-science, gravity, solar-system

It's the far future. Humans are *still!* increasing in population. We have developed habitable orbital structures and terraformed any planet we possibly could.

We reached the maximum potential for human life in our solar system, and then started importing more raw material from nearby solar systems (*and galaxies, if that still isn't enough*) using drones. Sure, it took a *long* time for the effort to pay off, but now we've got a stream of mass coming in, which we use to create more and more room for ourselves.

Our solar system is now an extremely busy place. It's gotten so busy, in fact, that on one eventful day - all the extra mass has caused catastrophic destruction.

What would be the first catastrophic thing to happen? How much mass would we have had to import?

Comment: Do you have a guess as to the scale you think an event may happen at?  Space masses can be remarkably deceiving.  (You also may find that the process required to bring that material has a catastrophic effect orders of magnitude before the mass itself starts to matter)

Comment: @CortAmmon I'm hoping an event would kill a great amount of people and possibly result in the destruction of at least a planet.. hoping, but I don't actually know the possibilities under this scenario.

Comment: As you add mass (and I mean _a lot_ of mass) to the system it's going to become very costly to maintain stable orbits. A collision between two massive objects might become a significant risk, though if we have the ability to move many solar masses worth of matter into our solar system I'd have to imagine we would be aware of this issue and be capable of preventing it (or at least evacuation in advance).

Comment: Samuel challenged my answer (and rightfully so) because I didn't really stick to the spirit of hard-science.  However, this brings up questions.  1) what timescale are you looking at... suns die after a while  2) what hard science mechanism are you using to bring the extra mass... and how does it cope with the momentum transfer needed to cross the void beteen solar systems before suns wink out.  The energy consumption of this process may FAR outstrip any effects of the mere mass, and the momentum transfer may have its own effects as well.

Comment: I actually asked this question, more in the spirit of curiosity. I was considering how space, (*realistic space*), is boring because of just how empty it is. I realized there are two things which are usually done to overcome this. 1. FTL - always being a couple seconds away from the exciting places. 2. Making space seem more full than it actually is (*usually most noticeable in Asteroid Fields*). So I was contemplating how to "fill" our solar system, to be more exciting in a more realistic way.

Comment: One of those ways I thought of was to gradually import matter, allowing us to fill our system with *people* - which arguably is the most chaotic and interesting thing I could fill it with. I realized there would eventually, potentially, be an issue with gravity if too much mass was added. I ask this question in the hopes of finding where that limit would be.

Comment: @CortAmmon With that in mind, the way I had first envisioned it was not to worry about time-scales, and that drones would reach their destination - be able to "refuel" or launch themselves from the material there, and be able to carry a bunch of matter back with them - slowly allowing the human population to grow - but to be honest my method of transportation is nothing more than a thought-reflex in order to explain the movement of material.

Comment: I just ran some numbers.  If you want to to to Alphacentauri for mass, and bring it back in 4.5 billion years (life expectancy of sun), you have to average .5m/s.  That's not much, but if you want to do it on a timescale where death of the sun isn't a big player, that minimum velocity raises sharply. (Amusing side calculuation: Let's say you wanted to steal Alpha Centauri outright, so you go there at .5m/s and come back at .5m/s.  Takes energy to accelerate their star our way, right?  Turns out its about equivalent to 1 second of solar output!  The sun is big!)

Comment: @CortAmmon *where death of the sun isn't a big player* - did you mean "is" a big player? Or else I might be misunderstanding something.

Comment: the rest of the sentence is needed.  If you want to do it on a timescale where the death of the sun *isn't* a big player, then you need to use much higher velocities so you get there and back in less time.  And, adding to that, the faster you succeed at traveling, the more we'd have to ask why we're spending all that effort to bring the mass back to our solar system, when we could leave instead.  We're not ready for billion year trips, but if that time gets into the millions or thousands, humans might "jump ship" and see if the sun shines brighter in Alpha Centauri.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30650/discussion-between-doubledouble-and-cort-ammon).

Comment: Where would the extra mass be placed? On planets and moons?

Comment: @HDE226868 On planets or moons, or on man-made satellites orbiting the planets or moons.

Answer (score 4):

Space is big.  You'd be surprised at just how big it is.  For example, go try to get a sense of how big the sun is compared to the Earth.  I'll wait.  As a hint, if the Sun was a basketball, the Earth would be nothing more than a grain of sand.  Now consider that the sun's volume is just 0.00000000000370% of the volume of the solar system.  I had to dig for good ratios to capture this one.  If you look at the water flow through your kidney versus the water flow of the entire Amazon river, you get pretty close to that ratio.  There's a lot of space.

Space is big.  Really big.

Rather than trying to fill that up noticeably to cause a cataclysm, consider what we're doing with it.  How robust are our construction principles?  How much raw energy do we bring along with all that mass to keep ourselves warm?

Consider having the humans accidentally construct a domino effect when some unforeseen contingency breaks up.  Maybe we have systems that try to station-keep all of our new mass in safe orbits, and it freaks out when one of our stations goes poof.  Now, instead of it being the mass that causes problems (which would take a lot), its our own "ingenuity."

And note that I had to invent a station-keeping mechanism to make things serious.  Space is so big that its hard to even effect a cataclysm if you try, unless we add some algorithmic effect to magnify the damages.  Alternatively, one might also look at the extremely exotic methods needed to move large sums of matter from one solar system to another, and the unforeseen consequences of that.  I'm assuming you don't have FTL, or the problem would be phrased very differently, so go ahead and play catch with trillions of tons of mass over multiple lightyear distances without missing a catch.  Dropping the ball on a moon certainly counts as an error in most interstellar baseball rulebooks.

Or perhaps just try to cope with the issues of the sun winking out.  It may take less time for that to happen than to actually fill the solar system.

Space is big.  Really big.

Comment: Note the hard-science tag.

Comment: @Samuel Point.  I am making an additional comment to work with that.

Comment: I think Cort's answer is appropriate.  Room is not the issue, resources and how we use them are the issue.  Quantifying the resources and human utilization of those resources will be impossible because we have not yet conducted a good survey of the solar system's resources.  Furthermore we do not know what sort of resources our new technologies might require.  The best we could do is perform a linear extrapolation of current trends and apply that to what we *believe* is available.  I don't think we can get a *hard* science answer to this.

Comment: @Jim2B is there not a hard science answer to how full our solar system can get before things start to collapse?

Comment: I think some of the tricky bit will be deciding what qualifies as a cataclysmic event.  There's plenty of things that start to go wrong before we see celestial grade events occur.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, raw mass is unlikely to cause a problem unless you try to import an entire star. Since colliding stars is fairly obviously an instant cataclysm (the sun will be fine, if a little larger, but anything around it won't be), we'll ignore that scenario. Bringing in an intact gas giant is a similarly bad idea - it will disturb any nearby orbits even though the same mass added to the sun or spread around the system would make no difference.

If the mass is in the form of conventional space stations with nuclear power and stationkeeping capability, you can build literally trillions without noticeably affecting anything. For some hard numbers, let's assume we can pack a solar orbit as densely as GEO, with around 100km between satellites. A single circular orbit at the heliopause (18,000,000,000 km) would have room for 1,130,400,000 satellites. If you aren't confined to the ecliptic, you should be able to fill a billion orbits that size without significant risk of collision.

For something more likely to cause problems, maybe everyone wants to live on a planet. They want something that will survive the fall of civilization without needing maintenance - a big rock in a stable orbit with nothing more complicated than some orbital mirrors to keep it habitable. Putting a few dozen earth size rocks in a 1AU orbit seems reasonably doable - you'll have to be really careful where you put them, but that should be well within the capabilities of this civilization.

Unlike the satellites, these planets do not have stationkeeping capability. You do have the technology to throw planets between stars at significant fractions of light speed, but that involves pointing a planet-sized laser at them - not something you can reasonably do after the planet is colonized.

With everything so delicately balanced it would only take one error with the deceleration beam to start the planets crashing into each other.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it usually takes just one human to cause massive destruction, but that's in a more metaphoric sense.  I did read the clarification, and as it was pointed out, space is just so unbelievably big it's nearly beyond human comprehension to come up with enough populated sites to cause a problem due to mass.  However, it takes a lot less mass to cause 'massive' destruction if the mass is in the right place.  One planet placed in the right orbit could collide with another planet and cause some pretty massive destruction.  Perhaps it comes in from an extremely eccentric orbit and hits a planet in such a way to put debris into the path of another planet or space station or ship, or inhabited asteroid?

I hope that helps.